# MissingServletRequestParameterException but it is present

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to call Spring Controller from JS with a requesParam but I'm always getting `Required String parameter 'id' is not present`

**The call in my JSP:**

```
window.location.href='controllerTest/controller1/function1?id='+idFromJSFunction;
```

**My Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller1")
public class Controller1{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/function1")
    public ModelAndView function1(@RequestParam("id") String idFromJSP, HttpServletRequest request,
        RedirectAttributes redAttr) {

    //Doing things
    }

}
```

If I put `reuired=false`, id is always `null`.

Any hint?

Comment: probably `idFromJSFunction` is empty

Comment: @Plirkee idFromJSFunction is not empty because I can see that URL is correct. When I make the call I can see in the browser: http:// localhost:7001/rootContext/controllerTest/controller1/function1?id=6